# Is showing the sso key a security issue?

Tags: gigya

I realized that when we access the URL https://cdns.gigya.com/js/gigya.js?apikey=MY_API_KEY

A SSO KEY is shown, along with *baseDomains*

Are these values something an attacker can exploit?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Answer needs to be thirty characters: The answer is "No".

Comment: Thank you. What arguments do you have?

Comment: sso keys are only used internally by the websdk, they are just the api key of the parent site of the group and api keys are public.

Answer (score 0):

Gigya API keys are public keys. An attacker can not do anything with the Gigya API keys because even in the case of trying to use them in a Frontend, it won't work because of the domain must be allow-listed in Gigya.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).